# Como mudar texto de span quando botão for clicado?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu criei um botão para download de arquivos no meu site, que exibe o texto "Baixar (XXX MB)".

```
<a class="a_btn_download" href="LINK DO ARQUIVO'><span class="span_baixar">Baixar</span> <span class="span_size">(XXX MB)</span></a>
```

Como o tamanho do arquivo é grande o download demora um pouco pra começar. Então eu quero que o span com a classe "span_size", que mostra o tamanho do arquivo, tenha o texto alterado pra "Aguarde...".

Como posso fazer com um código javascript?

Comment: Seleciona o elemento no DOM com a função `querySelector` ou `getElementsByClassName`, depois altera o conteúdo do mesmo através da propriedade `textContent` ou `innerHTML`. Quer tentar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar um evento de clique no botão e quando for pressionado muda o texto.

```js
let a_btn_download = document.querySelectorAll(".a_btn_download")

for( let property in a_btn_download ){
    
   a_btn_download[property].onclick = function() {
   
      this.lastChild.innerHTML = "aguarde..."

  }
}
```

```html
<a class="a_btn_download" href="LINK DO ARQUIVO"><span class="span_baixar">Baixar</span> <span class="span_size">(XXX MB)</span></a>

<a class="a_btn_download" href="LINK DO ARQUIVO"><span class="span_baixar">Baixar</span> <span class="span_size">(XXX MB)</span></a>

<a class="a_btn_download" href="LINK DO ARQUIVO"><span class="span_baixar">Baixar</span> <span class="span_size">(XXX MB)</span></a>
```

Comment: Esse código deu certo. Mas agora surgiu um problema. A página tem mais de um botão de download, mas esse código só está funcionando no primeiro botão.

Comment: Todos os botões tem a mesma estrutura com as mesmas classes ?

Comment: Sim, apenas mudando o link.

Comment: Editei o código, basicamente fiz um looping para atribuir o evento para todos os botões, porém usei o [for in] que é um método q tem bastante suporte aos browsers, mas você pode usar o forEach também que tem um pouco menos de suporte.

Comment: Em vez de usar `event.target` bastaria um `this`.

Comment: Agora sim está funcionando bem. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @WeslleyHordman Editei o código, por favor atualize-o, obrigado pelas dicas Sam e Anderson Carlos Woss

Comment: Ok, já estou utilizando o código atualizado.